# right-aligning social icons within navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am building a website where I want to have a collapsible navigation bar in the top left, and a social media bar in the to right. I want it so that the social icons always aligned with the navigation links.

My approach is as follows: create a row with 2 columns. The first column has the navigation bar, and the second column has all the social media icons. I use "justify-content-between" to push these two columns to the opposite ends.

I'm sort of there. I have the collapsible navigation bar and the social links.

The problem is that the social bar is not in the top right; it is adjacent to the navigation bar. I think it is because my row is not taking up the full width of the page.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href=".">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="teaching">Teaching</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="research">Ressearch</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="outreach">Outreach</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="personal">Personal</a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <a href="mailto: arjunc@pitt.edu" target="_blank"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/000000/important-mail.png"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/arjunc12" target="_blank"> <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/24/000000/twitter.png"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/arjunc12" target="_blank"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/24/000000/instagram-new.png"/></a>
            <a href="http://writers-fakeblock.blogspot.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/24/000000/blogger.png"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like. I would like the social bar to be pushed to the far right.

[image]

Here is a [link](https://www.arjun-chandrasekhar-teaching.com/#) to my website in case you want to see it in your own browser or see the full source code

Please be nice to be :) I am a complete novice with web programming. It is possible there are some deeper underlying issues that resulted from me doing is in a very ad-hoc, non-idiomatic manner.

**Update:** I figured out the issue. The nav should be inside the row/column, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

add `justify-self-end` class to social icons wrapper

Comment: You mean make it <div class="col-auto jusity-self-end">? That didn't work, unfortunately. Looks the same for me.